# Setting specific pixel colours on a matplotlib colourmap, depending on value/data type (and preserve range)

Tags: python, matplotlib, colormap

I have a CSV data file that has data of the (simplified) form:

```
1.2, 2.2,   o,   s
1.7,   s, 2.4, 2.9
  o, 0.9, 0.1, NaN
1.4,   s, 0.5, 0.9
```

NB: This contains the character 'o', not the number zero (0). This file is mixed with characters that indicate different types of "failed" measurements. These matrices are typically much larger than a 4x4 grid.

I would like to plot these matrices on a colour map using `matplotlib` but where each failed measurement value is assigned its own colour on the plot, whilst preserving the colour range of legitimate data.

Something with logic like e.g.
`

```
if data == 'o':
   pixel_colour = 'red'

if data == 's':
   pixel_colour = 'black'

if data == 'NaN':
   pixel_colour = 'white'
```

`
I have seen this helpful post ([Changing colours of pixels of plt.imshow() image.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26692946/changing-colours-of-pixels-of-plt-imshow-image)) already but I can't think of how to get this to handle heterogeneous data types.

Comment: Do you have just o and s?   Or are there more categories?

Comment: For now, just 'o' and 's'. NaN represents missing data in this case, which I should have specified.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but you may just want to use "over" and "under" colors in your colormap: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11386054/python-matplotlib-change-default-color-for-values-exceeding-colorbar-range

Comment: To answer your question you can always pass an rgbA array to imshow and it will just use those values.

Comment: Thank you for sharing! That makes sense but I think the issue would be assigning large numbers to, say, 's' will throw off the scale of the colour map. Also, this is only useful for 2 different types of 'failed' measurement. We have 3 and potentially more in the future. Thanks again though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To properly answer your question, you can mask the bad values, norm, map to RGBA, and then fill in the other colors as you like

```py
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[1.2, 2.2,   'o',   's', 2.5],
                 [1.7,   's', 2.4, 2.9, 1.7],
                 ['o', 0.9, 0.1, 'NaN', 0.4]])
data[data == 'NaN'] = -4000           
data[data == 'o'] = -5000           
data[data == 's'] = -6000
data = data.astype(np.float64)

norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=0, vmax=3)
cmap = plt.get_cmap('viridis')

# convert from 0-1:
datan = norm(data)
# convert to rgba:
rgba = cmap(datan)
# Fill in colours for the out of range data:
rgba[data==-4000, :] = [1, 1, 1, 1]
rgba[data==-5000, :] = [1, 0, 0, 1]
rgba[data==-6000, :] = [0, 1, 1, 1]

# plot:
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.imshow(rgba)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: This is great, thank you! However, I can't seem to get a colour bar to work on the side of the plot?

Getting an error:
RuntimeError: No mappable was found to use for colorbar creation. Fi
rst define a mappable such as an image (with imshow) or a contour se
t (with contourf).

Comment: For future reference: I eventually fixed the colour bar issue by following the matplotlib colorbar docs: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/color/colorbar_basics.html