# How to change specific position's color with matplotlib.pyplot.imshow?

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

I have a numpy array, and I use following codes to draw a simple picture.

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.show(image, cmap='gray')
```

I also have a list containing the several positions of the image, and I'd like to change the colors of these positions on the same picture.
For example, I have another list like this:

```
pos = [(0,1),(3,6)...]
```

I'd like to change the pixel's color according to this. For other pixels they remain the same.
How can I do that?

Comment: I hope {this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26692946/changing-colours-of-pixels-of-plt-imshow-image) will help you. This example is a way to normalize the colormap used and graph it, specifying the RGBA of the color at a particular location in the range from 0 to 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't mind copying or modifying the image you can acess the pixel value in the array :

```
import numpy as np

image = np.eye(10)

pos = [(0,1),(3,6)]
values_to_set  = [125,255]
for p, val in zip(pos, values_to_set):
    image[p] = val
```